# $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ minimizing ${1\over{20}}\sum_{i=1}^n{{\text{lcm}(x_1,\ldots,x_n})\over{x_i}}+{{1}\over{\sum_{i=1}^n{1\over{x_i}}}}?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, optimization

What nonempty set of distinct positive integers $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ minimizes the expression$${1\over{20}} \sum_{i = 1}^n {{\text{lcm}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n - 1}, x_n})\over{x_i}} + {{1}\over{\sum_{i = 1}^n {1\over{x_i}} }}?$$The naive thing to try out is just the singleton $x_1 = 1$, where the expression evaluates to $${1\over{20}} + 1 = {{21}\over{20}}.$$But I'm wondering if we can do even better than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ and define $S_1(X) := \frac{1}{20} \sum_{x_i \in X} \frac{\text{lcm}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)}{x_i}$ and $S_2(X) := \left(\sum_{x_i \in X} \frac{1}{x_i}\right)^{-1}$. The goal is to find a set $X$ of positive integers that minimizes $S(X) := S_1(X) + S_2(X)$.

Define $f(n) := \frac{1 + 2 + \ldots + n}{20}$ and $g(n) := \left(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-1}$. Since all the terms $\frac{\text{lcm}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)}{x_i}$ in the sum for $S_1(X)$ are distinct positive integers, we see that $S_1(X) \ge f(n)$. On the other hand, it is also clear that $S_2(X) \ge g(n)$, so that for all sets $X$ we have the lower bound $S(X) \ge f(n) + g(n)$.

By calculating $f(n) + g(n)$ for $1 \le n \le 5$, one can check that this sum is minimized for $n = 2$, with a value of $\frac{49}{60}$. This value can actually be obtained by choosing $X = \{1, 2\}$.

If $n \ge 6$, then $S(X) > S_1(X) \ge f(6) = \frac{21}{20} > \frac{49}{60}$.

We conclude that the set $X$ that minimizes $S(X)$ equals $X = \{1, 2\}$.

In fact, I can prove that $X = \{1, 2\}$, $X = \{1, 3\}$ and $X = \{1, 2, 4\}$ are the only three sets for which $S(X) < \frac{21}{20}$. In order to prove this, we need to check a few possibilities separately. Assume $1 \le x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_n$.

If $n = 1$, then $S(X) = \frac{1}{20} + x_1 \ge \frac{21}{20}$. For $n = 2$, if $x_1 \ge 2$, then $S_2(X) \ge \frac{6}{5} > \frac{21}{20}$ and if $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 \ge 4$, then $S_1(X) + S_2(X) \ge \frac{5}{20} + \frac{4}{5} = \frac{21}{20}$. So the only two options are $X = \{1, 2\}$ with $S(X) = \frac{49}{60}$ and $X = \{1, 3\}$ with $S(X) = \frac{19}{20}$.

Skipping $n = 3$ for the moment, when $n = 4$, there are two possibilities; $S_1(X) = \frac{10}{20}$ or $S_1(X) \ge \frac{11}{20}$. If $S_1(X) = \frac{10}{20}$, then $x_4$ must be a multiple of $12$, since $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are then $\frac{x_4}{4}, \frac{x_4}{3}, \frac{x_4}{2}$ respectively. This which would lead to $S_2(X) \ge \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{12}\right)^{-1} = \frac{6}{5}$, which is larger than $\frac{21}{20}$. We may therefore assume $S_1(X) \ge \frac{11}{20}$. In this case we would need $\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{x_2} + \frac{1}{x_3} + \frac{1}{x_4} > 2$, in order for $S_1(X) + S_2(X)$ to be smaller than $\frac{21}{20}$. The inequality $\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{x_2} + \frac{1}{x_3} + \frac{1}{x_4} > 2$ is however only possible with $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 3$ and $x_4 \in \{4,5\}$, and neither of these provide a solution.

For $n = 5$ we get $f(n) + g(n) = \frac{651}{548} > \frac{21}{20}$ and for $n \ge 6$ we already saw $f(n) \ge \frac{21}{20}$, so the only possibility we still need to consider is $n = 3$. And with $n = 3$ we have to check four different cases.

**Case 1.** $S_1(X) = \frac{6}{20}$.

In this case $x_3$ must be divisible by $6$ and we get $S_2(X) \ge \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} \right)^{-1} = 1$, implying $S(X) \ge \frac{26}{20} > \frac{21}{20}$.

**Case 2.** $S_1(X) = \frac{7}{20}$.

The only way to get $7$ by adding $3$ distinct positive integers is by $1 + 2 + 4$, so this way we obtain the aforementioned solution $X = \{1, 2, 4 \}$ with $S(X) = \frac{129}{140}$.

**Case 3.** $S_1(X) = \frac{8}{20}$.

There are two ways to get $8$ by adding $3$ distinct positive integers; either $1 + 3 + 4$ or $1 + 2 + 5$. In the first case we deduce that $x_3$ needs to be divisible by $12$ and in the second case $x_3$ needs to be divisible by $10$. This means that $S_2(X)$ is either at least $\left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{12} \right)^{-1} = \frac{3}{2}$ or $\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{10} \right)^{-1} = \frac{5}{4}$. In both cases we see that it's larger than $\frac{21}{20}$.

**Case 4.** $S_1(X) \ge \frac{9}{20}$.

In this final case we see that $S_2(X)$ needs to be smaller than $\frac{3}{5}$ and the only way to do this with $n = 3$ is if $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2$ and $x_3 \in \{3, 4, 5\}$ and it is quickly checked that these do not lead to new solutions.

As a final edit, I am interested to see where this problem originated from. In particular, without any context, the constant $\frac{1}{20}$ feels a bit arbitrary to me. I have therefore also tried to generalize my result to see if I could put it in a broader and more natural seeming context. This has led to the following. For a set $X$ of positive integers and for $c$ a positive real constant, let $S(c, X)$ be defined as follows:

$$S(c, X) = c \sum_{x_i \in X} \frac{\text{lcm}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)}{x_i} + \left(\sum_{x_i \in X} \frac{1}{x_i}\right)^{-1}$$

Then we have the following proposition: if $c \ge \frac{1}{6}$, then the singleton set $X = \{1\}$ minimizes $S(c,X)$. For $c$ with $\frac{1}{42} \le c \le \frac{1}{6}$ we have that $X = \{1, 2\}$ is optimal, and if $c < \frac{1}{42}$, then $X = \{1, 2, 4\}$ is better than either of these.